# What are all the frequencies on the sectional chart?

Tags: usa, aeronautical-charts

See the image below of a screenshot of DFW - Dallas Fortworth Sectional chart.

There are a multiple frequencies. Based on what I learnt on Sportys so far, a CTAF has a (C), then UNICOM has a UNICOM written after the frequency.

How should one know which frequency is what, when someone sees a sectional like the one in the link. Especially, where the Control Tower frequency, and/ or arrival, departure frequency etc.

[image]

https://ibb.co/s1YWhCT

Comment: Have you looked through the [Chart User's Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/) to see what each frequency is? If so, what exactly isn't clear? I'm not sure if you're asking how to read the chart, or [how to know which frequencies you'll need during a flight](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26743/62)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pondlife said, the information you want is found in the [*Aeronautical Chart User's Guide — VFR Charting Products*](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/) publication.

**Control Tower** frequencies are the ones shown in blue Airport Data Groupings with **CT -** in front of them.

**Approach Control** frequencies that are relevant to VFR pilots are shown in blue (Class B) or magenta (Class C) boxes at the outskirts of Class C and Class B airspace, but are otherwise not shown on the "map" portion of the sectional. However there is a listing at the edge of the sectional/TAC of **Class B, Class C, TRSA, and Selected [i.e. certain Class D] Approach Control Frequencies**. Note that if you are using an online map like SkyVector you will have to select a specific sectional instead of "World VFR" in order to see the outer non-map areas.

If there is a *specific* frequency on a *specific* chart that you have a question about after consulting the Chart User's Guide you can edit your question to describe it.